# What does let 5 = 10 do? Is it not an assignment operation?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, variable-assignment, assignment-operator, let

If I say `let 5 = 10`, why does `5 + 1` return `6` instead of `11`?

Comment: An immediate answer would be "because you can't redefine what `5` is". However, I am actually quite surprised by writing `let 5 = 10` being even possible!

Comment: what you can do is `overload` the `+`: `let 1+1=3 in 1+1` ;)

Comment: btw: I think the `5` in `let 5 = 10` is still a pattern (just one that is never matched) so it will not bind anything (as in `let (x,5) = (6,6)` )

Comment: @Carsten Indeed -- that is what [Chapter 4 of the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html) says, assuming that I'm parsing it correctly.

Comment: If I say let 5 = 10, when I type 5 into ghci it returns 10

Comment: @brett It doesn't happen [here](http://ghc.io). If reproduced, it would be a serious bug in ghci.

Comment: Even if you do declare 5=10 you should run a 5==10 check and see if it is returning true or not ...

Comment: `Prelude> :set -XBangPatterns`  Then
`Prelude> let !5 = 10` Yields
`*** Exception: <interactive>:9:5-11: Non-exhaustive patterns in pattern binding`.  Laziness was hiding the failed pattern match and allowed your misunderstanding to persist.

Answer (score 53):

When you say

```
let 5 = 10
```

it's not a redefinition of 5, it's a pattern matching, the same  which occurs when you say

```
foo 5 = undefined
 ... foo 10 ...
```

The pattern simply fails if it's ever matched.

In let-expressions the match is lazy. This means the match is only being done when a variable bound by it is evaluated. This allows us to write things like

```
 let foo = undefined in 10
```

In your expression, no variable is bound, so the pattern is never matched.

Arguably such patterns with no variables make no sense in let-bindings and should be detected by the compiler, but the language doesn't forbid them.

Comment: Reassuringly `let (5,x) = (10,True) in x` delivers `*** Exception: <interactive>:2:5-21: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern (5, x)`.

Comment: This is silly for let-bindings, but not for all: e.g. `only5 xs = [5 | 5 <- xs]` makes sense (if you're OK with lists `fail`).

Comment: @user3237465 yes, I only meant let-bindings. Updating.

Comment: pigworker: and `let (~5,x) = (10,True) in x` returns `True` only because we've explicitly told the compiler to assume the 5 pattern matched.

Comment: Similar case: `let [] = [1,2] in True`

Answer (score 17):

Basically,

```
let 5 = 10 in ...
```

is equivalent to

```
case 10 of ~5 -> ...
```

Note the `~`, which marks a *lazy*, or *irrefutable pattern*. This is a pattern that matches everything, and that postpones the match to the point where some variable is actually demanded. There are no variables in the pattern `5`, so nothing ever happens.

This corner case is quite useless, and arguably the compiler should emit a warning here.

To clarify the meaning of lazy patterns, consider this:

```
case f 3 of
  (x,y) -> g 10 x y
```

here `f 3` is evaluated first (to WHNF), exposing the pair constructor. Then `x,y` are bound to the (not yet evaluated) pair components. Finally, `g 10` is computed, the result is applied to `x` (which might be demanded now), and then to `y` (which may cause `x` or `y` to be demanded).

By comparison,

```
case f 3 of
  ~(x,y) -> g 10 x y
```

does not start with evaluating `f 3`. Instead `x` is bound to the unevaluated `fst (f 3)` and `y` is bound to the unevaluated `snd (f 3)`. We instead start with evaluating `g 10`. Then, we apply that to `x`: this might cause `x` to be demanded, triggering the evaluation of `f 3`. Then, we apply the result to `y`, causing a similar evaluation. Most implementation will actually *share* the result of `f 3` between `x` and `y` so that it is computed at most once.

Comment: Similar pattern matches can be useful. In particular, it's not unusual to write `catch m $ \ ~MyException -> ...`, where the non-binding lazy pattern match is a convenient way to provide the exception type. But using a numeric literal in such a fashion seems like a stretch.

Answer (score 2):

As @n.m. is saying, you are pattern matching. Here are some examples.

Pattern matches can succeed

```
Prelude> let (a, 10) = (15, 10) in a
15
```

or fail.

```
Prelude> let (a, 10) = (15, 15) in a
*** Exception: <interactive>:5:5-22: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern (a, 10)
```

Since Haskell is lazy, your code will succeed if you do not use the resulting value. This is essentially what you're doing:

```
Prelude> let (a, 10) = (15, 15) in "Something else"
"Something else"
```

Note that the types must still check:

```
Prelude> let (a, 10, 999) = (15, 15) in "Something else"

<interactive>:7:20: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(t, Integer, Integer)’
                  with actual type ‘(Integer, Integer)’
    • In the expression: (15, 15)
      In a pattern binding: (a, 10, 999) = (15, 15)
      In the expression: let (a, 10, 999) = (15, 15) in "Something else"
    • Relevant bindings include a :: t (bound at <interactive>:7:6)
```

Comment: "Since Haskell is lazy, your code will succeed if you do not use the resulting value" -- It is worth mentioning it also matters that `let` bindings match lazily by default. `case (15, 15) of { (a, 10) -> "Something else" }` crashes, while `case (15, 15) of { ~(a, 10) -> "Something else" }` (which, thanks to the lazy match, [is equivalent to your third example](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-440003.12)) succeeds.

Comment: @duplode, I think that lazy default in `let` and `where` was a bad idea, and is the reason bang patterns can be confusing sometimes.

Comment: @dfeuer What about binding to an infinite list? For example `let nats = [1..] in takeWhile isOkay nats`

Comment: @Teodor, I was referring to *patterns* on the LHS in `let` and `where`, not simple variable bindings. I think that `let p = e1 in e2` should be exactly the same as `case e1 of p -> e2`, no matter what `p` looks like. Unfortunately, there's no fixing that in Haskell, but hopefully future languages will consider doing it my way.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks for the clarification. I agree with your point.