# Haskell rare pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

In haskell, I can do:

```
s@"Hello" = s
```

The result is:

```
>s
>"
```

It begins to print the String but never ends, what is goin on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `@"Hello"` is irrelevant here, all it does is fix the type to `String`. You get the same behaviour with

```
s :: String
s = s
```

Which is semantically equivalent to

```
s' :: String
s' = undefined
```

which gives the result

```
Prelude> s'
"*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

What I mean by “semantically equivalent” is, both `s` and `s'` are examples of *bottom values*, i.e. values from that “sin bin of error values any type contains, thanks to non-strictness”. As soon as you hit a bottom value, the pure Haskell language is basically powerless and has give in to, well, *undefined*, “impure behaviour”, like letting you wait forever or throwing an exception.

However, again thanks to non-strictness, this needs not necessarily happen. When printing a value, the first thing that happens is, the `Show` instance is invoked and asked to produce a string. A Haskell string is a lazy list. And the `show` of *any* string begins with `"`, therefore even if the string itself is utterly undefined, `show` will manage to produce that one character.

We can observe this more sheltered with

```
Prelude> head $ show s
'"'
```

Comment: Wow, that's a perfect explanaition, even I could understand a little more this issue, thanks a lot! Nice to have big masters Hanging around here

Answer (score 8):

In `let`s and top level expressions everything on the left-hand side of the `=` is in scope on the right-hand side. So you've created a looping "bottom" value.

Notice this behaves the same way:

```
Prelude> let s = (s::String)
Prelude> s
"
```

That's because (simplifying) `print` on `String` is defined something equivalent to:

```
printString chars = putChar '"' >> mapM_ putChar chars
```

Because `chars` is a loop the `mapM_ putChar chars` appears to hang.

Comment: If you are here... when tried to investigate this behavior I've came across the fact that you can do `let 1=2` without any consequences. Can you explain this?

Comment: @Eugene: This has to do with laziness – as long as you never examine the value, the pattern match won't have a chance to fail.  So `let x@1 = 2 in x` will fail, as will `let !1 = 2 in ()`.  But with `let 1 = 2 in ()`, nothing will force Haskell to actually perform the requested pattern match.

Comment: The last one is funny. Though I thought one can't have constants (and expressions) on the lhs

Comment: Likewise let True = False in True?

Comment: @Damian: Yeah, it's the same thing.  (Note that the `True` in the body of the let is *not* the same as the `True` in the pattern match!)  More questions in this vein are probably best asked as a new question :-)

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky, I can see! Maybe another day I come up with that one :D.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks a lot for the explaination, it was very revealing

Comment: @DamianLattenero That wasn't me :)

Comment: Sorry, hahaha I wanted to say @jberryman, but of course, this is his answer.... haha

Comment: @EugeneSh. See also: [*About \`let 5 = 10\`*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33006500/2751851)