# Is True = False? Understanding binding and pattern matching

Tags: haskell, binding, pattern-matching

A friend of us is teaching to us the basics of functional programming in Haskell, and he started to write the rarest thing I ever saw:

He started with something not so amazing, but pretty cool:

```
(x,y) = (10,20)
(z:zs) = 0 : [1..]
```

and shows in the prelude:

```
prelude> x
10
prelude> z
0
prelude> takeN 3 zs
[1,2,3]
```

so far, so good... I didn't know you could bind the values like that

```
(x,y) = (10,20)
(z:zs) = 0 : [1..]
True = False -- HERE
```

What!? Everyone in the class thought, ok, something will go wrong, but not even **the code compiled**, then it runs:

```
prelude> x
10
prelude> 4
4
prelude> True
True
```

(I read the question [What does `let 5 = 10` do? Is it not an assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006500/about-let-5-10) and I'm not using any let here, in my example I write the code in a file and the execute it, so my question is not answered yet, none of that answers are useful for me.)

Comment: Please highlight the differences if you re-ask a question that has previously been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: What exactly is the question

Comment: In our case, `True = False` is an irrefutable pattern, and since there are no variables bounded by it nothing forces the match between the `True` pattern and the value `False`.

Comment: @DamianLattenero I'll reply to your Meta question here, in order to evade the Meta effect. I think that question of yours has value as a duplicate, and shouldn't be deleted. I guess the reopen vote has attracted extra attention to it, leading to the delete votes. As luck would have it, there is an easy way out in this case: abandon that other question in favour of this one -- it is essentially identical, was closed against the same target, and even has helpful supplementary answers. As a bonus, this question *can't* be deleted by normal means, because I used it as a duplicate target elsewhere.

Comment: @duplode I have a better idea, why don't I change the other question putting there the link to this question? and you mark this question that question as duplicate of this one? can you do that?

Comment: @duplode I'm curius now, what's the "meta effect?"

Comment: @DamianLattenero [1/2] If I were to do that, there would be no need for you to edit a link into it. However, it would be quite odd to change duplicate targets to make a question point at an identical question which is also a duplicate. (Strictly speaking, I don't think there is an acute need to do anything. I'm only suggesting that because of your concern about the delete votes, and because the questions are identical, so in principle we only need one of them to exist.)

Comment: @DamianLattenero [2/2] The Meta effect is when a post gets lots of extra votes because it is being discussed in a Meta question. I suspect the Meta crowd would find the existence of this second question problematic, potentially leading to downvotes and/or a derailed discussion.

Comment: @duplode ok... it is sad... and I will sacrifice rep, but it's ok, the better for the site is to close the other question. thanks for your time

Comment: @DamianLattenero If nothing else, this resolution should, quite appropriately, earn you the Disciplined badge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196591/discussion-between-damian-lattenero-and-duplode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `where` and `let` introduce defining equations using *lazy* patterns.

In any module, all the top-level definitions are under a `where`.

```
module Main where
         -- ^^^^^

x, y :: Int
(x, y) = undefined

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "hello!"
```

The above program will print "hello", as intended. The pattern matching against `(x, y)` would diverge if it were strict, but since it is lazy it does not -- the `undefined` expression never gets evaluated.

Definitions typed in GHCi are also under an implicit `let`.

After knowing this, the issue mentioned in the question is exactly the one in the [`let 5 = 10`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006500/about-let-5-10) question.

Comment: `let 5 = 10` and `let True = False` are pretty useless, but someone could actually want to write, say, `let Just _ = x`, though `PartialTypeSignatures` and `TypeApplications` are better for that these days.

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell a let “binding” is doing pattern matching. There are precisely two types of pattern-matching-binding in Haskell: You can either write `P = x` where `P` is a pattern or you may write `v1 p1 p2 ... pn = x` where each `pi` is a pattern. This defines (part of) a function `v1`. What is a pattern?
A pattern is either a variable `v` which causes `v` to be bound to whatever is being matched when the match is successful. Or a pattern may be a constant like 7 where when the matching is done it succeeds only if the thing being matched is equal to the constant. Or a pattern may be a variant of a data type:  If `Foo` is a variant (constructor) for the type `Bar` taking n parameters then `Foo p1 p2 ... pn`, where the `pi` are patterns, is a pattern which looks at an object of type `Bar` and successfully matches if it is of the `Foo` variant and each of the `pi` successfully match.

Because Haskell is lazy, the only way to force the pattern matching to happen is to use a variable which was bound by pattern matching. So one may force the binding of `x` in `let (x,5)=(6,6)` by using `x` and this cause a matching failure. If a variant has no parameters there is no way for the matching to be forced so there is no way for the match to fail. Thus `let True = False` would fail if you ever got the match to happen but because there is no way to get the match to happen, there is no error. Note that you are not rebinding `True` but using it as a pattern with no arguments.